# What are the seven Kingdoms?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I have just started watching GoT and have tons of questions? But for now....

What are the **Seven Kingdoms**? Can the capitals, ruling houses, and words of those houses be included as well? If possible, a map would help a lot.

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/135439/19561 for a detailed answer.

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65697/16465 .Read @Chanandler Bong answer.

Comment: @Clsoe-voters It's not too broad, it might be too easy to found but most of the stuff can be googled too.

Comment: If you're interested in this subject, you really want to read the books.  Martin goes into exquisite detail about the rich history of Westeros, as well as the Free Cities, Volantis, Slaver's Bay and Qarth.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful? If so, you consider marking it as "Accepted"?

Answer (score 18):

From *The World of Ice and Fire* (a companion book to the main ASOIAF series):

> For centuries it has been the custom to speak of the Seven Kingdoms of Westeros. This familiar usage derives from the seven great kingdoms that held sway over most of Westeros below the Wall during years immediately preceding Aegon’s Conquest. Yet even then, the term was far from exact, for one of those “kingdoms” was ruled by a princess rather than a king (Dorne), and Aegon Targaryen’s own “kingdom” of Dragonstone was never included in the count. Nonetheless, the term endures. Just as we speak of the Hundred Kingdoms of yore, though there was never a time when Westeros was actually divided into a hundred independent states, we must bow to common usage and talk of the Seven Kingdoms, despite the imprecision.

Now the Seven Kingdoms *before* Aegon's Conquest were:

1. Kingdom of the North
2. Kingdom of the Reach
3. Kingdom of Stormlands
4. Kingdom of Isles and Rivers
5. Kingdom of Westerlands
6. Kingdom of Vale and Mountain
7. Principality of Dorne

After Aegon's Conquest the Kingdoms were restructured a bit and the former rulers or in some cases allies of Aegon that supported him were given the title of Lord Paramount. However, during Robert Rebellion and the The War of Five Kings there has been much upheaval. These are how the kingdoms are situated the current time.

1. Paramount Lordship of Vale and Mountain

   - Currently ruled by House Arryn
   - House words are "As High as Honor"
   - House seat is The Eyrie
2. Paramount Lordship of Iron Islands

   - Currently ruled by House Greyjoy
   - House words are "We Do Not Sow"
   - House seat is Pyke
3. Paramount Lordship of Westerlands

   - Currently ruled by House Lannister
   - House words are "Here Me Roar"
   - House seat is Casterly Rock
4. Paramount Lordship of North

   - Currently ruled by House Stark in show; House Bolton in books
   - House Stark words "Winter is Coming"; House Bolton words "Our Blades are Sharp"
   - House seat is Winterfell
5. Paramount Lordship of the Reach

   - Currently ruled House Tyrell
   - House words are "Growing Strong"
   - House seat is Highgarden
6. Paramount Lordship of Stormlands

   - No current Lord Paramount in show; House Baratheon in books
   - House words are "Ours is the Fury"
   - House seat is Storm's End
7. Paramount Lordship of Riverlands

   - Currently ruled by House Frey in show; House Baelish in books
   - House words are "We Stand Together" (maybe); none
   - House seat is The Twins; Harrenhal
8. Royal fief of Crownlands

   - Currently ruled by House Lannister in show, House Baratheon in Books
   - "House" seat is King's Landing
9. Principality of Dorne

   - Currently ruled by Ellaria Sand in show; House Martell in Books
   - House words are "Unbowed, Unbent, Unbroken"
   - House seat is Sunspear

For a map you can see here:

[image: westeros]

<sub>[Inspired by this answer of SFF.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/135439/57310)</sub>