# Which three kingdoms is Jaime referring to?

Tags: dialogue, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones S07E01*, Cersei and Jaime had a discussion, with this dialogue:

> "I am the Queen of the Seven Kingdoms.” – Cersei
>
> "Well, three at best.” – Jaime

What three kingdoms is Jaime including as still under Cersei's control in this quote?

Comment: well Lannister,vale,greyjoy i guess.

Comment: @AravindhGopi This is before Jaime knows about Euron's upcoming visit.

Comment: cersei and jaimie themselves having 2 kingdoms Baratheon's + Lannisters

Comment: @AravindhGopi Not Vale, they know about Rise of Jon Snow so it is only natural that they would also know that Valemen have cast their lot with the Northmen

Comment: Somewhat [related](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65697/which-kingdoms-are-in-rebellion-even-after-the-battle-of-the-blackwater?rq=1).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The three Kingdoms are:

1. Westerlands
2. Riverlands
3. Crownlands/Stormlands

Crownlands [aren't a separate Kingdom historically](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/135439/54887) but Jaime isn't the most well-versed guy in law. In the books it is noted many times that he is very dumb when it comes to history and Law. But then again, he could be referring to Stormlands instead but Stormlands are uncertain as well given that [Cersei isn't a Baratheon and has no claim to the throne](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133040/54887).

> It can't be Iron Islands as at that time Jaime didn't know about
>  Greyjoy alliance.

When he says "at best", he's mentioning the ideal scenario. If you are overly-optimistic and everything goes well, those are the only three Kingdoms Cersei has control over. But Jaime knows Riverlands are uncertain

> given murder of the Frey family

and so are the Stormlands. Therefore he uses "At best".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62507/discussion-on-answer-by-aegon-which-three-kingdoms-is-jaime-referring-to).